# How to input text in EditText with 2 groups of RadioButtons

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, collection-radio-buttons

I have 2 groups of radio buttons. And I want to make when `btn1stDigitBrown1` of 1st group is pressed it shows on display "1" just as it is in code below and when `btn2ndDigitBlack0` from 2nd group is pressed it should also show one number next to the number that was just written on `EditText`, for example, "10". And when the button of the 2nd group is pressed (for example `btn2ndDigitBlack0`) before button from 1st group is pressed, it should automatically show on `EditText` "10". For now, when `RadioButton` from the 2nd group is pressed it rewrites number written already on `EditText`. This is my code:

```
    View.OnClickListener listener1stDigit = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn1stDigitBrown1:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("1");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn1stDigitRed2:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("2");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn1stDigitOrange3:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("3");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn1stDigitYellow4:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("4");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn1stDigitGreen5:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("5");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn1stDigitBlue6:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("6");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn1stDigitViolet7:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("7");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn1stDigitGrey8:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("8");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn1stDigitWhite9:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("9");
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    };

    btn1stDigitBrown1.setOnClickListener(listener1stDigit);
    btn1stDigitRed2.setOnClickListener(listener1stDigit);
    btn1stDigitOrange3.setOnClickListener(listener1stDigit);
    btn1stDigitYellow4.setOnClickListener(listener1stDigit);
    btn1stDigitGreen5.setOnClickListener(listener1stDigit);
    btn1stDigitBlue6.setOnClickListener(listener1stDigit);
    btn1stDigitViolet7.setOnClickListener(listener1stDigit);
    btn1stDigitGrey8.setOnClickListener(listener1stDigit);
    btn1stDigitWhite9.setOnClickListener(listener1stDigit);

    View.OnClickListener listener2ndDigit = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitBlack0:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("0");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitBrown1:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("1");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitRed2:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("2");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitOrange3:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("3");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitYellow4:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("4");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitGreen5:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("5");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitBlue6:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("6");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitViolet7:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("7");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitGrey8:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("8");
                    break;
                case R.id.btn2ndDigitWhite9:
                    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText)).setText("9");
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    };

    btn2ndDigitBlack0.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
    btn2ndtDigitBrown1.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
    btn2ndDigitRed2.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
    btn2ndDigitOrange3.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
    btn2ndDigitYellow4.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
    btn2ndDigitGreen5.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
    btn2ndDigitBlue6.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
    btn2ndDigitViolet7.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
    btn2ndDigitGrey8.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
    btn2ndDigitWhite9.setOnClickListener(listener2ndDigit);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is to learn how to manipulate strings
You should read [this](https://www.guru99.com/java-strings.html)

What you should do in the 2nd listener is concatenate the new number

```
switch (view.getId()) {
     case R.id.btn2ndDigitBlack0: {
         EditText editText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.resistText))
         String oldString = editText.getText()
         if (oldString.length <= 1) {
            editText.setText(oldString + "0")
         } else {
             editText.setText(oldString.substring(0, 1) + "0")
         }
         }
     ...
```

Comment: I also need when button from 2nd group is pressed 2nd time it should rewrite number that was written 1st time. For example EditText currently shows "10", and when btn2ndDigitBrown1 is pressed it should display "11", not "101"

Comment: I updated the answer, but I firmly believe that it is easier for you to read a bit more about string manipulation

Answer (score 0):

setText(...) rewrite text in TextView. To add text at the end use append(...)

for example:

```java
TextView textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.some_text_view);
textView.setText("1"); //text contain 1
textView.setText("2"); //text contain 2
textView.setText("3"); //text contain 3
textView.append("1"); //text contain 31
textView.append("2"); //text contain 312
...
```